# How to create a wordpress page automatically when a subscriber is registered to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Further i need the automatically created page to be edited by the respective subscribe only and when published it should be visible to all users who visit the website

Comment: hi Vishwanath, it would be great, if you could add a bit more details to your question. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: lets consider 'A' as a subscriber who registers on site1 now a page with page title as 'A' (same name as subscriber) should be created and  'A' can only edit a page with title 'A' he can not edit any other page

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to use the [user_register](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) hook and execute the function in which you create the post, and to create a post, you need to use [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function

```
add_action('user_register','my_function');

function my_function($user_id){
  // Create post object
   $my_post = array(
     'post_title'    => 'Title of page',
     'post_type' => 'post', // Set type of your post
     'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
     'post_status'   => 'publish', // Page published
     'post_author'   => $user_id // Assign page author
   );
 
   // Insert the post into the database
   wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```

You can also manage [Roles and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) for your post type

**Examples**:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208739/193674
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108375/193674